# Trying to reconnect webpack dev server

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

Webpack dev server trying to reconnect after i push ctrl+c in terminal. in terminal it quit but in browser console it constantly writting [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOMlT.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your errors (and code if any) as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for text, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This is desired behavior. The Website tries to connect to your dev server to get updates on the Site (rebuilds) but if you stop the server, it of course can't connect anymore.